# Git PR for multiple repositories

Tags: git

Currently I am thinking of making something like this

[image]

The idea is that I want to have one shared library living in its own repository while each of the Solution (A/B/C) live in a separate repository. Solution (A/B/C) are going to link reference the share library repository.

This way I can reuse shared library for any of the potential new project that I am going to make.

The problem is, I do not know how to make pull request to work across repositories. Lets say I need to change something in Solution A which I would need to change shared library too. From what I have read I should be able to commit to both repositories at the same time but I couldn't find any documentation on how to make PR work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution here would be to put the shared library in a git submodule in each of the repositories. That way, you can commit changes to the shared library from either of your repositories, and can even depend on different versions or branchs of it in each repository.

Comment: will a single PR work for a commit to both SolutionA and shared library?

Comment: It depends on what you call pull request. If it is a mail with "Please pull from", then yes. If you are talking about some other kind of PR; like GitHub's, then it might or might not be supported by the service. Expect not. You need to commit your changes to the shared library first, and then each project will pull it (see it as a rebase if you want) in due time. Pull requests are often meant to pull objects into a single repository, which would need a single commit to be used for multiple repositories at once. This is technically impossible with git. However, submodules are the way to go.

Comment: Well, another solution might be to create your own PR system, of course, merging multiple patches at once. Or even merging the same patches in the three different repositories. But I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: yea it really sux that I have to create multiple PR for one commit and people would have to look for multiple PRs to merge. I will wait a while to see if anyone has some brilliant solutions. If not I am willing to accept this answer as this is impossible to do

Answer (score 0):

While I would like to say that create PR in your own repository. It enables you to merge also. But if you do clone others repository than you can add and then commit to PR. You can create folders in your repository and merge them. You can also create folders in clone ones repositories and you can commit them.Just like above (A/B/C) I think this can be in the form of new files and folders that refer to your main or clone repository and you share with yourself or with others.